# Some errors have occurred with Thread

Tags: c++, pthreads

```cpp
void* bubbleSort(int *data,int len){
    int i = 0, j = 0, temp = 0;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ ){
        for ( j = i + 1; j < len ; j++ ){
            if(data[i]>data[j]){
                temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
int *data =new int[1000000];
    int len = 0;
    int k = 0;
      while( file >> data[k]) {
      k++;
      len = len + 1;
   } // while 
    file.close();

int input = 0;
scanf("%d",&input );  // thread
pthread_t thread[input];
  for ( int i = 1 ; i < input ; i ++){
    pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,&bubbleSort,(void*)data,len);    
   }   

  for ( int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
    cout << data[i]<< " ";
  }
}
```

I firstly use the thread to bubble sort, I searched some websites to see what it writes. Now I have some errors.

```sh
[Error] invalid conversion from 'void* ( * )(int*,int)( * )(void*)'
```

I don't know how fix it...

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using pthreads instead of std::thread here? Moving to the more modern interface would make this a lot more straightforward for you.

Comment: ... and then try to parallellize the notoriously hard to parallellize bubble sort on your first attempt, as well?

Comment: @Frank Because I referenced someone else's code.

Comment: I'd recommend `std::thread` instead of `pthread`. Also, your code will cause several different threads to sort the same array at the same time. That's not going to turn out well. Also, you have UB when accessing your threads, due to an off-by-one issue.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, quote the full error message. However, first extract a [mcve] from your code, removing anything not necessary to reproduce the problem. That said, I agree with Frank, don't invest too much time learning the POSIX threads interface but go with portable C++ threads.

Comment: @yui `Because I referenced someone else's code.` That's not the best way to learn a new language.

Comment: @eerorika I know :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my code looks like crash ? (sort using pthead)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61605656/why-my-code-looks-like-crash-sort-using-pthead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the function you want your threads to run can only take one argument. If you want to pass different values to it, you'll have to use a struct (with `data` and `len`, in your case).

Second, you don't have to do this: `&bubbleSort`. You should pass the function without referencing it: `bubbleSort`.

Third, you have to expect the argument of `bubbleSort` to be a `void *` and cast it to something else inside of it.

```
typedef struct {
    int *data;
    int len;
} Args;

void* bubbleSort(void * param){
    Args * args = (Args *) param;
    int len = args->len;
    int * data = args->data;
    ...
}

int main(){
    Args * arguments; 
    // here you initialize your arguments with data and len
    ...

    for (int i = 1 ; i < input ; i ++){
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, bubbleSort, arguments);   
    }   
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd like to ask again. I have 1million data, but output just about 60 data

Comment: Well, you might want to create a new question for that

Comment: Do you really believe that this is a good advice for bubble sort?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov all I did was fix the errors he had with the usage of the `pthread` library, which is what the question is about

Comment: Here is a follow up question from the same person: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61605656/why-my-code-looks-like-crash-sort-using-pthead, where he makes exactly the same mistake. I believe that this question/answer pair is confusing other users and should be duplicated/removed.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. That second question doesn't contribute very much to this site. I thought they should make a separate question because this one was strictly about a compilation error (and the only thing I did in my answer was fix that). But I think you are right, we could've tried to fix it here.